# How to get user information instead of just ID sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, backend

I am using sequelize with mysql,

I have 3 models

1. posts
2. Comments
3. users

posts model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Post = sequelize.define('Post', {
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    content: DataTypes.TEXT,
    userId: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {});
  Post.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    Post.hasMany(models.Comment, {
      foreignKey: 'postId',
      as: 'comments',
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    })
    Post.belongsTo(models.User, {
      foreignKey: 'userId',
      as: 'author',
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    })
  };
  return Post;
};
```

comments model

```
const user = require("./user");

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Comment = sequelize.define(
    "Comment",
    {
      postId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      comment: DataTypes.TEXT,
      userId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    {}
  );
  Comment.associate = function (models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    Comment.belongsTo(
      models.User,
      {
        foreignKey: "userId",
        as: "author",
        me: "name",
      },
      { name: user.name }
    );
    Comment.belongsTo(models.Post, {
      foreignKey: "postId",
      as: "post",
    });
  };
  return Comment;
};
```

users model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define(
    "User",
    {
      name: DataTypes.STRING,
      email: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    {}
  );
  User.associate = function (models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    User.hasMany(models.Post, {
      foreignKey: "userId",
      as: "posts",
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
    });

    User.hasMany(models.Comment, {
      foreignKey: "userId",
      as: "comments",
      onDelete: "CASCADE",
    });
  };
  return User;
};
```

and following is my response i am getting when i execute the following query

```
const getAllPosts = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const posts = await models.Post.findAll({
      include: [
        {
          model: models.Comment,
          as: "comments"
        },
        {
          model: models.User,
          as: "author"
        }
      ]
    });
    return res.status(200).json({ posts });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).send(error.message);
  }
};
```

RESPONSE

```
 "posts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "1st post ever on this server",
      "content": "This is the content of the first post published on this type or architecture",
      "userId": 1,
      "createdAt": "2021-01-31T10:00:45.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2021-01-31T10:00:45.000Z",
      "comments": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "postId": 1,
          "comment": "this is the comment on first post",


          "userId": 1, // Also need a key val pair of username and his email ID just instead of UserID


          "createdAt": null,
          "updatedAt": null
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "postId": 1,
          "comment": "comment second",
          "userId": 1,
          "createdAt": "2021-01-31T15:34:27.000Z",
          "updatedAt": "2021-01-31T15:34:27.000Z"
        }
      ],
      "author": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test user",
        "email": "testuser@gmail.com",
        "createdAt": null,
        "updatedAt": null
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I need the user name of commented user name and email for which i have fields in the table
but i am just getting user ID
how can i go about it,
I am very much new in sequelize, I tried but i am getting get same hasMany and benlongsTo results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see you doing, you need to run a nested `include` when getting the comment.

Try this modified code.

```
const getAllPosts = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const posts = await models.Post.findAll({
      include: [
        {
          model: models.Comment,
          as: "comments",
          include: [
              {
              model: models.User,
              as: "author"
              }
           ]  
        },
        {
          model: models.User,
          as: "author"
        }
      ]
    });
    return res.status(200).json({ posts });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).send(error.message);
  }
};
```

Comment: also what if i want to eleminate certain column like created at or updatedAt

Comment: you can use the exclude keyword
 {
          model: models.User,
          as: "author",
         exclude: ["createdAt","updatedAt"]
        }